# obtain the index of elements in a list that satisfy a condition

Tags: python, list

I am trying to index the positions of a list of integers to obtain the position of the intergers that are >0.

This is my list:

```
paying=[0,0,0,1,0,3,4,0,5]
```

And this is the desired output:

```
[3,5,6,8]

rdo=paying[paying>0]
```

and tried:

```
rdo=paying.index(paying>0)
```

The output is in both cases

```
typeerror > not suported between instances of list and int
```

Comment: `paying[paying>0]` is numpy syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=list%20comprehension#list-comprehensions) and [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) built-in function:

```
paying=[0,0,0,1,0,3,4,0,5]
print([i for i, e in enumerate(paying) if e > 0])
```

> `[3, 5, 6, 8]`

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension.

```
paying=[0,0,0,1,0,3,4,0,5]
result = [index for index, value in enumerate(paying) if value > 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use enumerate:

```
paying=[0,0,0,1,0,3,4,0,5]
[i for i, e in enumerate(paying) if e > 0]
```

OR

```
[paying.index(e) for e in paying if e > 0]

Result:  [3, 5, 6, 8]
```